# Set Builder Notation for all positive odd integers greater than or equal to 7

Tags: discrete-mathematics

A question in my text book for a course I'm taking over winter is asking me to give the set builder notation for **(X∪Y)'** *[i.e. the complement of the union of set X and set Y]* given that **U=Z^+** *[i.e. the universal set is that of all positive integers]*, **X={1,2,3,4,5}**, and **Y={2n | n ∈ Z^+}** *[i.e. all positive even integers]*. Basically, I'm looking for the set builder notation for **the compliment of {1,2,3,4,5,6,8,10,12,14,...}**.

I've figured out that the complement is **{7,9,11,13,15,17,...}**, or all positive odd integers greater-than or equal-to 7.

The issue is that the textbook doesn't give a very clear explanation as to what is and isn't correct when writing set builder notation. I've searched the internet for explanations and examples, but I've just been getting a lot of vague and/or conflicting information that doesn't tell me whether I've got the right set builder notation.

The answer that I have is **(X∪Y)' = {n ∈ Z^+ | 2n+1 ≥ 7}**.

Can someone tell me if this is correct? Or how I should change it if it isn't? 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Let's try to read what you wrote.  $\{n\in \Bbb Z^+\mid 2n+1\geq 7\}$ is the set of all positive natural numbers such that if you were to double the amount and add one it would be greater than or equal to $7$.  Unfortunately, that would correspond to the set $\{3,4,5,6,7,\dots\}$ since $2n+1\geq 7$ is true for $3$ since $2\cdot 3 + 1\geq 7$ and is also true for $4$ since $2\cdot 4 + 1\geq 7$ and so on.

Comment: There are many ways to write a correct answer here.  One such way is to write it as $\{2n+1 \mid n\in \Bbb Z^+, n\geq 3\}$.  These are all numbers of the form $2n+1$ such that $n$ is a positive integer and $n$ is greater than or equal to $3$ (*which makes $2n+1$ greater than or equal to $7$*).